# Thrift / Fedora 24 no Python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, thrift

**./configure**

```
thrift 1.0.0-dev

Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building C (GLib) Library .... : yes
Building Java Library ........ : yes
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : **no**
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : no
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
Building Dart Library ........ : no
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : yes
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : yes
Building Lua Library ......... : no

C++ Library:
   Build TZlibTransport ...... : yes
   Build TNonblockingServer .. : yes
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt4) .... : no
   Build TQTcpServer (Qt5) .... : yes

Java Library:
   Using javac ............... : javac
   Using java ................ : java
   Using ant ................. : /bin/ant

PHP Library:
   Using php-config .......... : /bin/php-config

Go Library:
   Using Go................... : /bin/go
   Using Go version........... : go version go1.6.3 linux/amd64

NodeJS Library:
   Using NodeJS .............. : /bin/node
   Using NodeJS version....... : v4.4.6

If something is missing that you think should be present,
please skim the output of configure to find the missing
component.  Details are present in config.log.
```

however during output it says both python and python3 are found. I also have python-devel and python3-devel installed

```
[root@dmitrypc thrift]# dnf list installed | grep 'python-devel'
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'rpmforge', disabling.
python-devel.x86_64                   2.7.12-1.fc24                @updates     
[root@dmitrypc thrift]# dnf list installed | grep 'python3-devel'
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'rpmforge', disabling.
python3-devel.x86_64                  3.5.1-12.fc24                @updates     
[root@dmitrypc thrift]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/configure.ac#L279-L289

```
if test "$with_python" = "yes";  then
  AC_PATH_PROG([PIP], [pip])
  AC_PATH_PROG([TRIAL], [trial])
  if test -n "$TRIAL" && test "x$PYTHON" != "x" && test "x$PYTHON" != "x:" ; then
    have_python="yes"
  fi  
fi
```

This requires the existence of the binaries: `pip` and `trial`. Try installing:

```
dnf install python2-twisted python3-twisted python-pip python3-pip
```